# Enable long paths on Win 11 Home

Tags: windows-11, path, group-policy

I need to enable long paths but my Win 11 Home edition does not have the group policy editor. Is there a way to enable this from the command line or install group policy editor on my machine?

Comment: Life is easier, faster, more secure and better with shorter paths.

Comment: Agreed! But not helpful.

Comment: Long file / folder names were implemented in Windows 95 in 1995 27 years ago. I survived within that limit since that time. There no practical necessity to alter Windows to do different.

Comment: It's not a matter of survival, it's a matter of making things a little easier. Anyway, I'm working on a Unity project that requires a plugin that must go in %USERPROFILE%\ProjectName\UnityProj\Assets\Plugins\PluginName\. This is a totally reasonable file structure but unfortunately the plugin at PluginName has its own extensive internal directory tree that I cannot alter without doing serious surgery on the plugin architecture itself. Enabling long paths is simply the path of least resistance (or so I thought).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way to enable long paths in Windows is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry)

It can be implemented by dropping the following into a .reg file and running it if you aren't comfortable editing the registry directly.

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
"LongPathsEnabled"=dword:00000001
```

The real problem 90% of the time is going to be getting applications to support it and not the file system.  Programmers hardcode [MAX_PATH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry) (260 chars) into their code and have been doing so for many many years.

It is lazy programming rather than using the windows heap to store the path names.

Some applications are written well enough to get around this but you will find more that don't work than do.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I want to also add that Windows may complain about paths being too long when **copying** files into a destination, but may not complain about the same files when **moving** them into the same destination.

Comment: What little support Explorer has for long paths (e.g. navigation, copying, moving, deleting files) is not changed by the `LongPathsEnabled` setting. Setting `LongPathsEnabled=1` will allow you to work with long paths at the command line, without having to use the special \\?\ prefix, but it does nothing for Explorer.